# login works even if the password incorrect using passportJs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to build authentication system for my website , and I am using express to build server , and passport local strategy for authentication  ,

```
let passport = require("passport");
let LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
let session = require("express-session");
app.use(session({ secret: "super secret" }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      return done(null, user);
    });
  })
);
```

when I signup , everything works and hashed password save in the database :

```
app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  let { fullname, email, username, password } = req.body;
  let user = new User({ fullname, email, username });
  await User.register(user, password);
  res.redirect("/login");
});
```

but when I try to login , the user logins if the username is exists regardless the password :

```
app.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureFlash: true,
    failureRedirect: "/login",
  }),
  async (req, res) => {
    let user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    if (user.lastLogin === undefined) {
      await User.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { lastLogin: Date.now() });
      res.redirect("/final-step");
    }

    res.redirect("/hi");
  }
);
```

Hope to help me , thanks

Comment: That's because you are not comparing the hash password in the local strategy. You are only looking for the user in the database with its username and returning if it exists. In that method you have to compare the password. Does that make sense for you?

Comment: can you tell me more please ? or give me docs for that method ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replace this code :

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      return done(null, user);
    });
  })
);
```

by :

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by adding

```
{ strictQuery: false }
```

in the schema like this:

```js
new Schema({}, {
    strictQuery: false
})
```

after that it was returning correct values